# How to diagnose hg push failure via SSH protocol

Tags: ssh, mercurial

I am trying to push changesets to a remote repository but the command seems to hand and nothing happens.

I'm on Windows 8.1, running a recent version of Mercurial (4.2). I can SSH into my server both using PuTTY and the OpenSSH client without a problem, whether using a key authentication or a password-based one.

My hgrc file has this:

```
[ui]
...
ssh = ssh -i "path_to_id_file" -2 -C

[defaults]
...
push = --debug
```

Here is the output I get on the command line:

```
pushing to ssh://myuser@mydomain.com//var/hgrepos/projectx
running ssh -i "path_to_id_file" -2 -C myuser@mydomain.com "hg -R /var/hgrepos/projectx serve --stdio"
sending hello command
sending between command
```

After that, nothing happens, for minutes. I was expecting to have to give the passphrase to my private key, like it happens when I simply type `ssh myuser@mydomain.com`. Ctrl+C does not do anything: I have to close the window.

Whether I'm using key or password authentication, the push always hangs indefinitely right after "sending between command". At some point, I thought that my key passphrase or password was expected but typing either didn't yield anything positive.

I've been administering this remote server and the repositories on it for years using HTTPS and Mercurial works as expected through that protocol. I'm gradually switching to key-based authentication and hg is the last step down this road.

Last info: `hg clone` exhibits the same behavior.

Some help diagnosing this would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have enabled SSH logs on the server and I get this when tail'ing `/var/log/secure` (these lines are the server-side match of the 4 lines that I gave earlier):

```
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[11654]: debug1: Forked child 15779.
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15779]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15779]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15779]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15779]: Connection from 176.188.xx.xx port 64160
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15779]: debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_7.5
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15779]: debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.5 pat OpenSSH*
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15779]: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15779]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com zlib@openssh.com
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com zlib@openssh.com
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST received
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY sent
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: KEX done
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: userauth-request for user userx service ssh-connection method none
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15779]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "userx"
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15779]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "176.188.xx.xx"
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15779]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Jul  4 13:15:40 vpsxxxxx sshd[15780]: debug1: userauth_send_banner: sent
```

Unless I am interpreting this the wrong way, it seems like the server is at the user authentication step while the client-side Mercurial is already sending commands on a communication line that is not opened yet since the user is not yet authenticated.

Comment: Add `-vvv` switches to the `ssh`.

Comment: `-vvv` had no effect with `hg push` but it affected the manual run of the command that hg runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally succeeded (again, I had done it years ago) in using SSH.

The problem seems to have been either using `ssh.exe` from the OpenSSH package, or (and this is documented on the webpages below that I've read today and which helped me out of this quagmire) that the server's key was not cached yet. And yet, I had manually connected to the server, as described in the question, in addition to numerous previous connections via Putty, MobaXterm and ssh.exe.

All that is needed (see https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WindowsInstall) is the Putty package and some configuration.

References:

- http://www.codza.com/mercurial-with-ssh-setup-on-windows
- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/AccessingSshRepositoriesFromWindows

The second one in particular is concise and helped me the most.

At this point, here is the relevant contents of my `.hgrc` file:

```
[ui]
...
ssh = D:\Programs\putty\plink.exe -ssh -agent -2 -C -i "path-to-ppk-file"
```

The `hgrc` file of my local repository that I'm converting to SSH instead of HTTPS contains:

```
[paths]
default-push=ssh://username@domain.tld:1234//var/hgrepos/projectx
```

Note that Mercurial will decompose that URI and present the appropriate parameters to the command indicated in `ui.ssh`. For instance, `hg clone ssh://username@domain.tld:1234//var/hgrepos/projectx` yields this output in the command line window:

```
G:\Data\Temp>hg clone ssh://username@domain.tld:1234//var/hgrepos/projectx
running D:\Programs\putty\plink.exe -ssh -agent -2 -C -i "path-to-ppk-file" username@domain.tld -P 1234 "hg -R /var/hgrepos/projectx serve --stdio"
sending hello command
sending between command
remote: 329
remote: capabilities: lookup changegroupsubset branchmap pushkey known getbundle unbundlehash batch stream bundle2=HG20%0Achangegroup%3D01%2C02%0Adige
sts%3Dmd5%2Csha1%2Csha512%0Aerror%3Dabort%2Cunsupportedcontent%2Cpushraced%2Cpushkey%0Ahgtagsfnodes%0Alistkeys%0Apushkey%0Aremote-changegroup%3Dhttp%2
Chttps unbundle=HG10GZ,HG10BZ,HG10UN
remote: 1
destination directory: projectx
query 1; heads
sending batch command
requesting all changes
sending getbundle command
bundle2-input-bundle: with-transaction
bundle2-input-part: "changegroup" (params: 1 mandatory 1 advisory) supported
adding changesets
add changeset 279e0cde0d10
....
```